# Multi word aliasses (Ubuntu)

Tags: bash, ubuntu

Is it possible to have a alias 'key' that consists of multiple words?

I tried (and without the ""):

```
nano ~/.bashrc
alias "git puhs"="git push"
source ~/.bashrc
>>bash: alias: `git puhs`: invalid alias name
```

Is this possible in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a alias 'key' that consists of multiple words?

No it is not possible. Alias name can't contain spaces. It is possible to "chain" aliases, by adding space on the previous alias value.

```
alias git="git "
alias puhs=push
```

For your sanity, do not do it that way and read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases .

Comment: That looks indeed as a better option. I'll mark this is as an answer when I am able to. Thank you for answering the question and suggesting a better way :)